# Insert only trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that sends an email ONLY when there's an insert. I currently get an email whether there's an insert or not and I WANT to get an email ONLY when there's an insert in the table. Here's how the trigger currently looks like

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[myTriggerName]  
ON [dbo].[myTableName]  
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
BEGIN  

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
      @recipients = 'MyRecipients',  
      @profile_name = 'DBAdmins',  
      @subject = 'MySubject',   
      @body = 'Body';  


END
```

Comment: Show us what have you done. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
     And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So what problem have you faced when tried to create such a trigger?

Comment: Please provide your trigger function code.

Comment: I think your biggest problem is not storing (or just not using) a timestamp to determine whether you had any inserts that need to be emailed. Seems like the email job could run with whatever frequency is appropriate. If you still need a trigger it would only be for the purpose of recording that timestamp or the fact that an email is due.

Answer (score 3):

I would be extremely careful to put extensive processing or things like sending e-mails directly into a trigger.

The trigger executes in the context of the calling transaction, and thus delays the completion of that transaction until it is done.

If you have external dependencies (like a SMTP server), you can quickly get into situations where you have timeouts etc.

A trigger should be extremely nimble, small and fast.

My recommendation would be:

- make a note into a separate table `EmailToSend` with all the necessary information you need (recipient, subject, body, date stored)

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER trgYourTableInsert
  ON dbo.YourTable
  AFTER INSERT
  AS 
     INSERT INTO dbo.EmailToSend(Recipient, Subject, Body)
     VALUES('john.doe@acme.org', 'Hello there', '.......')
  ```
- have a separate process (e.g. a scheduled stored procedure that runs once every hour) checking that table and doing the actual sending of the e-mails (without blocking any other processes / transactions) - something along the lines of:

  ```
  SELECT (list of columns)
  FROM dbo.EmailToSend
  WHERE DateSent IS NULL
  ```

  or something like that - it really heavily depends on what *exactly* you're putting into that table and how you want to handle this ....

Comment: Please can you script out the stored procedure that will be checking the EmailToSend table? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_I_tbl
    ON dbo.tbl
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @text = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + col
        FROM INSERTED
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'your_account@gmail.com',
        @subject = 'caption',
        @body = @text

END
GO
```

Comment: I would be *extremely careful* to put extensive processing or things like sending e-mails directly into a trigger. The trigger executes in the context of the calling transaction, and thus delays the completion of that transaction until the trigger is done. If you have external dependencies, you can quickly get into situations where you have timeouts etc. A trigger should be **extremely nimble and small** - make a note into a separate table `EmailToSend` and have a separate process (scheduled on an hourly basis) checking that table and sending out the e-mails